# html and jquery autocomplete (input values)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Hi allm I have a problem with inputs element.
Let's say I have an input element. And I use jquery autocomplete on it,

```
$(input).autocomplete({
   ...,
   source: function(request, response) { ... },
   select: function(e, ui) {
        var keyid = ui.item.iddo;
        var keylab = ui.item.label;
        $(this).attr('data-id', keyid);
        $(this).attr('value', keylab);
   }
});
```

When i select an element from the list data-id is correctly setted, and value is too and the input text is the correct one corresponding to value.

Now I have another  element and when I click it I need to change the data-id property of said input and its value aswell. I tried to remove autocomplete too:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.anchor', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    var ele_link = $(this);
    var datain  = ele_link.data('input');
    var dataid  = ele_link.data('id');
    var dataval = ele_link.text();
    var target_input = $('#' + datain);

    //try to remove autocomplete
    if($(target_input).attr('autocomplete')) {
        $(target_input).autocomplete('destroy');
        $(target_input).removeAttr('autocomplete'); //not actually needed
    }

    if(target_input.length) {
        target_input.attr('data-id', dataid);
        target_input.attr('value', dataval);
    }
});
```

And it works: the input data-id is correct and also value is changed, autocomplete is also removed.

Yet the **text** on the input field remains **unchanged**. It's the old one (the one when I selected the item in autocomplete box), even if value is correctly changed.

Main reason to remove autocomplete was because I had the same behaviour, but removing it didn't solve the problem.

What should I do?

Comment: `target_input.val(dataval)`

Comment: okok, ok it works, thank you Mouser. Id'like to know why. attr(value) changes value properly too...  aaaand prop('value') works too ahah.  Also post it as an answer, I'll accept as best one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's `val` instead of `attr` value:

```
if(target_input.length) {
    target_input.attr('data-id', dataid);
    target_input.val(dataval);
}
```